# Limit of Square Root of a Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a tridiagonal $n\times n$ matrix with the following format

$$ \mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b &        & \phantom{\ddots} & \phantom{\ddots}    \\
b & a & b      & \phantom{\ddots} &     \\
  & b & a      & \ddots           &     \\
  &   & \ddots & \ddots           & b   \\
\phantom{\ddots}  & \phantom{\ddots}  &  \phantom{\ddots}      & b                & a   \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

This matrix has eigenvalues equal to $$\lambda_k = a-2b\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{1+n}\right),\;\text{ for }\;k\in\{1,\dots,n\}.$$  It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_k=a-2b.$$

It is also symmetric which mean it can be diagonalized into $$\mathbf A= \mathbf Q \mathbf \Lambda \mathbf Q^T,\;\text{ so that  }\;\mathbf A^{1/2}= \mathbf Q \mathbf \Lambda^{1/2} \mathbf Q^T.$$

Is it possible to obtain an analitical formula for the elements of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf A^{1/2}$?

**Edit:** [This paper on tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices appears to be helpful](http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf).

Comment: More precisely, I think you are asking for the square root of the infinite matrix: $$ \mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b &        & \phantom{\ddots} & \phantom{\ddots}    \\
b & a & b      & \phantom{\ddots} &     \\
  & b & a      & \ddots           &     \\
  &   & \ddots & \ddots             \\
\phantom{\ddots}  & \phantom{\ddots}  &  \phantom{\ddots}                 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: On the other hand, you could mean the "doubly infinite" matrix operator, which is just a discrete convolution.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thank you for the clarification, I am indeed interested in the square root of the matrix in your first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The eigen-decomposition of an $n\times n$ real symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix is well-known: $\mathbf A$ can be orthogonally diagonalised as
$$
\mathbf A = Q\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\,Q^\top,
$$
where $\lambda_i = a+2b\cos\left(\frac{i\pi}{n+1}\right)$ and $q_{ij}=\sqrt{\frac2{n+1}}\sin\left(\frac{ij\pi}{n+1}\right)$. So, the entries of $\mathbf B=Q\operatorname{diag}(\sqrt{\lambda_1},\ldots,\sqrt{\lambda_n})\,Q^\top$ are given by
$$
b_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{\lambda_k}\,q_{ik}\,q_{jk}
=\frac{2}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{a+2b\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right)}\sin\left(\frac{ik\pi}{n+1}\right)\sin\left(\frac{jk\pi}{n+1}\right).
$$
Therefore, for any two given indices $i$ and $j$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{ij}
=2\int_0^1\sqrt{a+2b\cos(\pi x)}\,\sin(i\pi x)\,\sin(j\pi x)\,dx.
$$

Comment: +1 Can you suggest a good reference(s)  
with more details on this eigen-decomposition?

Comment: @g.kov I haven't any book at hand, but you may try Meyer's *Matrix Analysis and Applied Linear Algebra* or Demmel's *Applied Numerical Linear Algebra*. Or just google "symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix eigenvector". Basically, you solve $Av=\lambda v$ directly by treating it as a second-order linear recurrence relation.

Comment: Great thanks, Meyer's  must be the one.

Answer (score 2):

I just read the very good @user1551's post. I would like to make some remarks.

1. Necessarily, each matrix $(A_n)$ of the sequence must be $\geq 0$; that implies that the eigenvalues $(\lambda_k)$ must be $\geq 0$; finally, the condition is $a\geq 2|b|$.
2. The OP's remark $\lim \lambda_k=a-2b$ is non-sense, because (for example) the $\lambda_5$ of $A_{10}$ has no relation with the $\lambda_5$ of $A_{20}$.
3. The sequence $(A_n)$ is Toeplitz; let $t_i=a_{i+1,1},t_0=a_{i,i},t_{-i}=a_{1,i+1}$. Here $t_0=a,t_1=t_{-1}=b$ and the other are $0$ (the non-zero part is finite).

   In general, we associate the Fourier series $f(\lambda)=\sum_kt_ke^{ik\lambda}$; then $t_k=1/2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}f(\lambda) e^{-ik\lambda}d\lambda$ and it is assumed that $\sum_k |t_k|<\infty$ or $\sum_k t_k^2<\infty$. We denote by $T_n(f)$ the associated Toeplitz.
   Here $f(\lambda)=a+2b\cos(\lambda)$.
4. user1551 found $\lim \sqrt{A_n}=B$ in the sense of pointwise convergence. Note also that his proof shows that for "any" continuous function $g$,

$[\lim g(A_n)]_{i,j}=2\int_0^1g(a+2b\cos(\pi x))\,\sin(i\pi x)\,\sin(j\pi x)\,dx$.

Yet, such a limit is no more Toeplitz. Yet, we can find a Toeplitz limit in the following sense: two sequences $(A_n),(B_n)$ are said to be asymptotically equivalent (AE) when  they are bounded and when $tr((A_n-B_n)^T(A_n-B_n))=o(n)$. Note that the terms $A_n[i,j],B_n[i,j]$ may be very different when $i+j$ is small but they are close when $i+j$ is large.

In fact, one has: let $h,g$ be $2$ "good" Fourier series. Then $T_n(hg)$ and $T_n(h)T_n(g)$ or $T_n(g)T_n(h)$ are AE; moreover $T_n(g^{-1})$ and $T_n(g)^{-1}$ are AE.

Here we consider $T_n(\sqrt{f})=T_n(\sqrt{a+2b\cos(\lambda)})$.

Its associated sequence $t'_k$ is given by $t'_k=1/\pi\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{a+2b\cos\lambda}\cos(k\lambda)d\lambda$. It is easy to see that the series $|t'_k|$ or ${t'_k}^2$ converges; with a little bit of work, we should be able to show that the sequences $T_n(\sqrt{f})$ and $(\sqrt{A_n})$ are AE.